# Reducing the memory usage of Contacts Storage

Tags: htc-desire, contacts, storage

I have an HTC Desire running 2.2 and have noticed a lot of low memory warnings lately.
I think this is due to my Contacts Storage taking up 33+ mb of space.

How can I reduce or limit the amount of space the contacts take up?

Comment: Related, but not identical to: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17479/can-i-store-contacts-on-my-sd-card-how

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to reduce this number is to remove contacts. Now this could be setting apps like twitter and facebook to not sync contacts. But if you have pictures for everyone, it is going to increase the amount of storage as well.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try removing the contacts sync from Facebook etc. Will doing this shrink the memory usage or will it hold on to what it has got already?

Comment: I believe it will "unsync" but I am not 100%, i always tell it to not sync my facebook and twitter contacts.

Comment: After removing the twitter, facebook and last.fm contact sync, my storage dropped from 10MB+ to ~1MB. What's weird is that the contacts from those services are still in the list.

Comment: i know the twitter one is huge for me. I follow like 600+ people so to add that many would blow out the size of the database. i forgot about last.fm, I uninstalled that as soon as they announced they were going "pay for mobile" unless you have a WP7

Comment: After removing the sync from Facebook and Twitter the contents didn't reduce much. I had to delete all the contacts and let them resync from my Google account to finally get it to reduce the size.